# jOOQ sets timestamps with local time zone when UTC was expected

Tags: java, sql, jooq

In my jOOQ configuration file I have this line:

```
<javaTimeTypes>true</javaTimeTypes>
```

If I create this table in HSQLDB:

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (C1 TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW() ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL);
```

The generated jOOQ code is like this:

```
public final TableField<T1Record, LocalDateTime> C1 =
createField("C1", org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.LOCALDATETIME.nullable(false).
defaultValue(org.jooq.impl.DSL.field("LOCALTIMESTAMP",
org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.LOCALDATETIME)), this, "");
```

My JVM starts with the CET time zone and, no matter if I set it or not to GMT before creating the `DSLContext`, when inserting or updating rows (without setting a value explicitly) jOOQ always uses the CET time zone.

When using JDBC directly timestamps are inserted in GMT, which is what I want.
How can I configure jOOQ to have the same effect?

I'm checking the database contents with IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: In what time zone does the database run? Can you show the code how you fetch your data both with jOOQ, and with JDBC?

Comment: The database runs in embedded mode and is in the CET timezone. I'm checking the database contents via IntelliJ IDEA. The difference between jOOQ and raw JDBC is in how data is written. jOOQ sets the current value using the CET timezone while I expected it to be GMT, like raw JDBC. I edited the question to reflect these additional details.

Comment: Thanks, but can you show the actual code? Otherwise, it's hard to know what you mean by "raw JDBC". Alternatively, if you think you've found a bug, you could file an issue accompanied by an MCVE to help reproduce the problem: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ-mcve

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong data type. **`LocalDateTime` cannot represent a moment.** It is only a date and a time of day, without time zone or offset-from-UTC.

For a database column akin to the SQL-standard type `TIMESTAMP WITH TOME ZONE`, you should be using the `Instant`, `OffsetDateTime`, or `ZonedDateTime` classes.

This has been covered many many times already on Stack Overflow. Search to learn more.

Do not write your code to depend on the current default time zone of your JVM or your database. Specify the desired/expected zone or offset by passing explicitly the optional argument.

Comment: It's jOOQ which chose LocalDateTime. Apparently rightly so since I don't need an offset. As explained in the question.